# Efficient approach for movie ticket booking

Tags: database, algorithm

I am trying to figure out an efficient approach for movie ticket booking system. My main area of concern is in handling concurrency bookings by a user i.e two or more users trying to book the same seat for a given time.

Many solutions I went through online suggest handling concurrency through synchronisation i.e making the transactions visible to other users(similar to synchronise method/block in java).

What I feel is, the above approach may not be a scalable solution because if the number of requests increases to say a million/sec. We cannot expect those transactions to go linear, one by one. It will inject a lot of latency.

One of the approaches I have is to maintain a seating status like

```
EMPTY
IN_PROGRESS
BOOKED
```

When the payment button is clicked, status is changed from EMPTY to IN_PROGRESS. So the other user selecting the same seat and clicking the payment button, a check can be done on the status of the seat, if IN_PROGRESS then a suitable message can be displayed.

If the user who has gone through payment, if succeeded seat status is changed to BOOKED if the failed status will be changed to EMPTY.

Please tell me if there is any problem in my approach or is there any efficient approach to handle concurrency in seat booking. Thank you

Comment: Last one wins always works. Just don't tell your customers that.  But, honestly, two people would have to be booking the exact same thing at the exact same time, which is going to be a very small percentage of actual bookings. @RyanSchaefer he's working on the algorithm. The question contains that work. The question is okay, imho (and that's my website, so ... thanks?)

Comment: @Will Can you please elaborate your thought on "Last one wins"?

Comment: I dont see how the concurency problem is solved here. what if two users read the status on the same time before the status change to IN_PPROGRESS? of course you could use syncronized for it.

but if i got you right, you want to prevent the use of sync because of bad peformance and scalabiliy.

maybe a optimistic locking mechanism on database level could be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: The concurrency issue is solved by pretending there isn't one. You essentially seal the deal (before payment is issued) by marking the reservation complete, then go back and check if the same user is still reserved. If they aren't (i.e., two or more people were booking at the same time and the last one to book actually won the race), then cancel the booking before payment processed. If you don't want to chance that, mark the booked slot taken at the start of the process. Unbook it if they don't complete in a certain amount of time (tell them upfront).

Comment: @Will yeah this should work. seems for me that it's really close related to optimistic locking. (the idea is basicly the same)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach you can use here is to create a session that would expire after set number of minutes in your application. You want to offer your users the ability to select the seat numbers that are available.

Then send a POST request to the backend to lock those seats for that time. If the session expires, handle the event and unlock those seats. Otherwise, wait for the payment to succeed. Once the payment is processed, you just need to increase the locking window for the entire screening time.

With this approach you will be able to avoid problems of multiple users booking the same seat.

May use properties like `{ "locked" : true, "lock_expires": 163457987 }`.

If it gets too late, check for the `lock_expires` property and set  `locked: false` and redirect or refresh the page. Otherwise, set `"lock_expires": <time when screening ends>` .

A cron job can be implemented that runs after every minute to validate all locks. And if the `lock_expires` fails validation then `locked` is set to false automatically. This is useful if the user leaves the tab or closes the browser.

If anybody has a better solution then please comment and I will update it.